# javascript Retrieve input value from a selected checkbox and display multiple html file in same webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently this code opens 4 new tabs when all check box is selected, but I need all 4 page results ( 4 html ) files to open in single window or single html file  or similar to it, can any one help?

```js
function submit() {
    var box1 = document.getElementById('box1');
    var box2 = document.getElementById('box2');
    var box3 = document.getElementById('box3');
    var box4 = document.getElementById('box4');

    var urls = [];

    if (box1.checked) {
        urls.push(box1.value);
    }
    if (box2.checked) {
        urls.push(box2.value);
    }
    if (box3.checked) {
        urls.push(box3.value);
    }
    if (box4.checked) {
        urls.push(box4.value);
    }

    urls.forEach(function(url) {
        goToUrl(url);
    });
}

function goToUrl(url) {
    var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="no-j-boxes.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="checkbox" name="box1" value="http://box1url.com" id="box1"><label>box1</label><br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="box2" value="http://box2url.com" id="box2"><label>box2</label><br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="box3" value="http://box3url.com" id="box3"><label>box3</label><br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="box4" value="http://box4url.com" id="box4"><label>box4</label><br/>

        <input type="button" value="Submit" name="submitButton" onclick="submit()">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you want to open all links(choosen before submit is clicked) in new tabs in the same window  ?

Comment: yes in same window

Comment: i need multiple web pages which is selected to be displayed in single page

Comment: Exactly how in single page ? In iframes ? or in popup windows ?

Comment: I frames will be best option but I don't have knowledge on ho to achieve that result

Comment: i am trying your answer , i think i am doing some mistake  in implementing your code

Comment: just replace the loop and create a div with id your_div_where_you_put_all_iframes

Comment: Also can you create a fiddle on jsfiddle?

Comment: check my edited answer

Comment: Thank you , your answer helped me a lot , this is what i wanted !!  appreciate your Patience :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="no-j-boxes.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="checkbox" name="box1" value="http://box1url.com" id="box1"><label>box1</label><br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="box2" value="http://box2url.com" id="box2"><label>box2</label><br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="box3" value="http://box3url.com" id="box3"><label>box3</label><br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="box4" value="http://box4url.com" id="box4"><label>box4</label><br/>

        <input type="button" value="Submit" name="submitButton" onclick="submit()">
        <div id="your_div_where_you_put_all_iframes"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is script

```
<script>
function submit() {
    var box1 = document.getElementById('box1');
    var box2 = document.getElementById('box2');
    var box3 = document.getElementById('box3');
    var box4 = document.getElementById('box4');

    var urls = [];

    if (box1.checked) {
        urls.push(box1.value);
    }
    if (box2.checked) {
        urls.push(box2.value);
    }
    if (box3.checked) {
        urls.push(box3.value);
    }
    if (box4.checked) {
        urls.push(box4.value);
    }

    urls.forEach(function(url) {
        goToUrl(url);
    });
}

function goToUrl(url) {
    $('<iframe src="'+url+'" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" ></iframe>').appendTo('#your_div_where_you_put_all_iframes');
}

</script>
```

Try appending iframes like this. Hope it helps !